# Extruding without breaking edge loop

Tags: modeling

I want to model a shape with only quads. 
I created a circle shape and wanted to extrude some vertices away from the curve to form a keyhole. 
I am able to create the shape, but all extruded vertices are not connected to the circle shape anymore and I can´t select the Edge loop via shift-alt-LMB.
I wanted to select the keyhole in an easy way to add a bevel.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying create an extra edge loop around the keyhole to reinforce it for sub-dividing later?

Comment: No. I wanted to extrude the rectangle shape of the keyhole parallel to the outline of the cube. Deleted a few Vertices and extruded parallel to the outline with E, G, Y. But now all newly extruded veritces are disconnected from the Edge loop which was not intended.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you make a keyhole with all vertices connected.

1) Create a circle (say 32 vertices)
*Stay in Edit Mode*

2) Create a plane (also with 32 vertices)
Both the circle and the plane are a part of one object now.

3) Select both loops and connect them with *Edge->Bridge Edge Loops*
4) Almost done. All inner vertices are now connected into one loop.
5) You can now model you keyhole.

*Summary: Edge loops work. It’s all quads.*
[image]

Comment: Thats more or less how I created my keyhole. But instead of moving the lower 3 vertices I deleted them and extruded the rectangle shape of the keyhole out of the circle. With this all new vertices where disconnected from each other and not part of the edge loop anymore. How do you add Vertices which are part of the edge loop, or how would you select the inner shape without clicking on each of the edges?

Comment: @ThomasB Sure thing. - First, don't click on edges, but click on vertices when selecting the loop. Because you extruded your shape, there are corners, where the edge select mode will stop. - Second. If you really want to be able to select the loop in edge select mode, you need to rebuild your keyhole slightly, so that there are no corners in the loop. Compare closely my mesh with yours. My mesh doesn't have corners in the inner loop.